# Using Fiji image processing as a library in Java

Tags: java

Fiji (http://fiji.sc) is an app that, as far as I can tell, is written in Java and does image processing. Is there any way to remove the 'app' part and just use it as a normal library and import it in a normal Java project?

Right now the only two options available are 'scripts' and 'plugins'. Neither of which I want as they both live within this Fiji editor app. Is there a place just to download the image processing libraries and not the whole app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiji itself is a package distribution of the [ImageJ](https://github.com/imagej/imagej/) library, which may suit what you are trying to accomplish.

If you are using Maven, declare the dependencies in your `pom.xml`:

```
<parent>
  <groupId>net.imagej</groupId>
  <artifactId>pom-imagej</artifactId>
  <version>2.35</version>
</parent>
...
<dependency>
  <groupId>net.imagej</groupId>
  <artifactId>imagej</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

If not, you can grab the `.jar` off the [repository manager](http://maven.imagej.net/index.html#nexus-search;gav~net.imagej~imagej~~~~kw,versionexpand) on their website and include it as an external dependency. You can then start messing around with the library in your project:

```
public void loadAndDisplay(File file) {
    ImageJ ij = new ImageJ();
    Object data = ij.io().open(file);
    ij.ui().show(data);
}
```