# How can I download the imageJ library to code in java using eclipse?

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, plugins, imagej

I have reached till here: https://imagej.net/ij/developer/source/index.html. But after that, I don't know where to download this ij package and how to implement it into my code. Just for context, I'm using java and eclipse for coding.

I have already added the jar package mentioned in this article in the sense that I can see this in my referenced libraries: [Using Fiji image processing as a library in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39669361/using-fiji-image-processing-as-a-library-in-java). But when I copy paste the code snippet given at the end it shows that the build path is not fully formed yet and I have to rebuild the path. Additionally, this article: https://albert.rierol.net/imagej_programming_tutorials.html#ImageJ uses a lot of ImagePlus to work with plugins-- something that is my future goal.

Comment: https://github.com/imagej/tutorials might be a good place to start. Clone the repo. Start using Maven. It runs OK under Java 1.8

Comment: If you simply want to code ImageJ plugins, then you don't really need an IDE. I'd recommend to use plain ImageJ for this purpose and compile from there. Here is a doc that deals with most of what you need to know: <https://imagingbook.files.wordpress.com/2013/06/tutorial171.pdf>

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.